# cumulative sum between dates from using two dataframes

Tags: r, datetime, cumsum

I am trying to get the cumulative sum of a variable, between two dates.

I have two dataframes as follows:

Dataframe 1: has the event start/end:

```
# A tibble: 128 x 3
   event_start         event_end            year
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <int>
 1 2003-07-03 04:00:00 2003-07-04 10:00:00  2003
 2 2003-07-04 13:00:00 2003-07-05 18:00:00  2003
 3 2003-07-07 23:00:00 2003-07-09 17:00:00  2003
 4 2003-07-20 03:00:00 2003-07-22 19:00:00  2003
 5 2003-07-29 17:00:00 2003-07-30 18:00:00  2003
 6 2003-07-31 22:00:00 2003-08-03 20:00:00  2003
 7 2003-08-23 01:00:00 2003-08-24 13:00:00  2003
 8 2004-07-31 22:00:00 2004-08-05 03:00:00  2004
 9 2004-08-11 13:00:00 2004-08-12 17:00:00  2004
10 2004-08-26 01:00:00 2004-08-29 12:00:00  2004
...
```

Dataframe 2: has the hourly data from which I want to get cumulative sums for, and has almost 30,000 rows of data:

```
              datetime       Date month_day julian_day year rain_mm Temp_C discharge Air_Temp Net_Radiation Incoming_Shortwave_Radiation
1  2003-07-01 00:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  5.300     0.183     7.99        -40.31                         2.91
2  2003-07-01 01:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  4.910     0.178     7.15        -41.36                         1.63
3  2003-07-01 02:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  4.440     0.174     6.08        -42.76                         1.57
4  2003-07-01 03:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  4.210     0.168     5.61        -43.03                         1.63
5  2003-07-01 04:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  3.970     0.164     4.26        -41.51                         2.84
6  2003-07-01 05:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  3.740     0.155     3.58        -30.97                        15.27
7  2003-07-01 06:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  3.580     0.148     5.90         -3.40                        67.20
8  2003-07-01 07:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  3.660     0.141     9.47         75.78                       191.00
9  2003-07-01 08:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  4.130     0.136    12.52        180.31                       303.65
10 2003-07-01 09:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  4.755     0.129    14.47        303.49                       425.95
11 2003-07-01 10:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  5.925     0.125    15.41        433.01                       555.10
12 2003-07-01 11:00:00 2003-07-01     07-01        182 2003     0.0  7.095     0.122    16.66        536.61                       656.30
...
```

I am trying to get the cumulative sum of a variable, specifically "rain_mm", between each event_start and event_date datetime periods. The output dataframe that I am hoping to achieve will look like: (note: the cumsum_rain_mm values are made up for this example).

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   event_start         event_end            year   cumsum_rain_mm
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <int>
 1 2005-07-04 09:00:00 2005-07-05 12:00:00  2005   11.2
 2 2005-07-06 22:00:00 2005-07-08 00:00:00  2005   7.1
 3 2005-07-10 22:00:00 2005-07-11 23:00:00  2005   7.1
...
10 2005-08-27 02:00:00 2005-08-29 04:00:00  2005   5.8
11 2005-08-30 17:00:00 2007-07-01 20:00:00  2005   6.4
```

I can't simply aggregate per hour based on the two datetime columns, and am unsure where to go from here, especially due to the significant difference in the number of rows from each dataframe.

EDIT:
The initial solution worked, but now the sum_rain_mm column appears incorrect, and now looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 80 x 2
   interval                                         sum_rain_mm
   <Interval>                                             <dbl>
 1 2003-07-20 14:00:00 PDT--2003-07-21 03:00:00 PDT        412.
 2 2003-07-21 05:00:00 PDT--2003-07-22 01:00:00 PDT        412.
 3 2003-07-29 12:00:00 PDT--2003-07-30 02:00:00 PDT        412.
 4 2003-07-31 18:00:00 PDT--2003-08-01 15:00:00 PDT        412.
 5 2003-08-05 01:00:00 PDT--2003-08-05 14:00:00 PDT        412.
 6 2003-08-22 23:00:00 PDT--2003-08-23 23:00:00 PDT        412.
 7 2003-08-30 17:00:00 PDT--2003-08-31 06:00:00 PDT        412.
 8 2004-07-09 09:00:00 PDT--2004-07-11 03:00:00 PDT        412.
 9 2004-07-30 09:00:00 PDT--2004-07-31 09:00:00 PDT        412.
10 2004-08-02 02:00:00 PDT--2004-08-02 20:00:00 PDT        412.
# ... with 70 more rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution based in the tidyverse can look as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  crossing(df2) %>%
  mutate(across(c(event_start, event_end, dateTime), ymd_hms),
         interval = interval(event_start, event_end)) %>%
  filter(dateTime %within% interval) %>%
  group_by(interval) %>%
  mutate(sum_rain_mm = sum(rain_mm)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(interval, sum_rain_mm) %>%
  distinct()

#   interval                                         sum_rain_mm
#   <Interval>                                             <dbl>
# 1 2003-07-03 04:00:00 UTC--2003-07-04 10:00:00 UTC           1
# 2 2003-07-04 13:00:00 UTC--2003-07-05 18:00:00 UTC           2
# 3 2003-07-07 23:00:00 UTC--2003-07-09 17:00:00 UTC           6
```

Arbitrary demo data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(event_start = c("2003-07-03 04:00:00", "2003-07-04 13:00:00", 
"2003-07-07 23:00:00"), event_end = c("2003-07-04 10:00:00", 
"2003-07-05 18:00:00", "2003-07-09 17:00:00")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <- structure(list(dateTime = c("2003-07-03 04:00:00", "2003-07-04 13:00:00", 
"2003-07-07 23:00:00", "2003-07-07 23:00:01"), rain_mm = c(1, 
2, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: I've just gone back to this code again, and although it worked the first time, it's somehow not working properly this time.

My data set still looks the same as in the original post, but it seems like the mutate(sum_rain_mm = sum(rain_mm)) line is causing issue. The sum_rain_mm column in the output dataset all have values of 412. (with the period). I've updated the main question with how the dataframe looks, to add context.